# Procedurally Generating a Map

Tags: javascript, optimization, procedural-generation, cellular-automata

I've been trying to procedurally generate a planet for the game I'm making in Javascript. It generated a random noise grid and then iterates through it using cellular automata rules. This takes longer than 30 seconds for worlds larger than 1000x1000, so I was wondering if there was a way to generate it from a seed when it is loaded, like in Minecraft. Is there a way to generate the planet without having to do it all at once, or at least a faster way?

Here's the code, it generates the terrain and then displays it on the canvas.

```
scale = 0.25;

rngCount = 0;
function* RNG() {
    let seed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 10000;
    console.log(seed);
    let factor = 297;
    while(true) {
        seed = (seed * factor) - Math.floor(seed * factor);
        yield Math.floor(seed * 10000) / 10000;
    };
};

let generationRNG = RNG();

function clamp(min, max, value) {
    if(value < min) {
        return min;
    } else if(value > max) {
        return max;
    } else {
        return value;
    };
};

let map = [];
let mapW = 4096;
let mapH = 4096;

function iterate(e, map) {
    let height = map.length;
    let width = map[0].length;
    let updatedMap;
    let mapRow;
    let neighborCount; 
    let iy;
    let ix;

    for(i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        updatedMap = [];
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            mapRow = [];
            for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                neighborCount = 0;
                for(k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
                    for(l = -1 ; l <= 1; l++) {
                        if(y + k < 0) {
                            iy = height - 1;
                        } else if(y + k >= height) {
                            iy = 0;
                        } else {
                            iy = y + k;
                        };

                        if(x + l < 0) {
                            ix = width - 1;
                        } else if(x + l >= width) {
                            ix = 0;
                        } else {
                            ix = x + l;
                        };

                        if(!(l == 0 && k == 0)) {
                            neighborCount += map[iy][ix];
                        };
                    };
                };
                if(neighborCount >= 5) {
                    mapRow.push(1);
                } else if(neighborCount <= 3) {
                    mapRow.push(0);
                } else {
                    mapRow.push(map[y][x]);
                };
            };
            updatedMap.push(mapRow);
        };
        map = updatedMap;
    };

    return map;
};

function terrainGeneration() {
    let width = mapW / 16;
    let height = mapH / 16;
    let mapRow;
    let factor = 4;
    let fillPercent = 0.45
    let updatedMap;
    let map = [];

    for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        mapRow = [];
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            
            if(generationRNG.next().value <= fillPercent) {
                mapRow.push(1);
            } else {
                mapRow.push(0);
            };
        };
        map.push(mapRow);
    };
    
    map = iterate(10, map);

    for(a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
        if(a == 0) {
            fillPercent = 0.33;
        } else if (a == 1) {
            fillPercent = 0.2;
        };

        width *= factor;
        height *= factor;
        updatedMap = [];
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            mapRow = [];
            for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                mapRow.push(map[Math.floor(y / factor)][Math.floor(x / factor)]);
            };
            updatedMap.push(mapRow);
        };
        
        map = updatedMap;

        updatedMap = [];
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            mapRow = [];
            for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {

                if(map[y][x] == 1) {
                    if(generationRNG.next().value <= fillPercent) {
                        mapRow.push(0);
                    } else {
                        mapRow.push(1);
                    };
                } else {
                    if(generationRNG.next().value <= fillPercent) {
                        mapRow.push(1);
                    } else {
                        mapRow.push(0);
                    };
                };
            };
            updatedMap.push(mapRow);
        };
        map = updatedMap;

        map = iterate(5, map);
    };

    return map;
};

map = terrainGeneration();

for(i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(" + map[i][j] * 255 + ", " + map[i][j] * 255 + ", "  + map[i][j] * 255 + ", 1)";
        c.fillRect(j * scale, i * scale, scale, scale);
    };
};
c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)";
c.fillRect(0, 0, 40 * scale, 40 * scale);
```

is there a way to generate only a section of it from a seed and still have it coherently fit together? After I add biomes, the generation will take even longer, so I want to try to fix it now before I add more code. To test out the section generation I was going to have it generate the area around the cursor only.

here's an example of a 4096x4096 map that took 3 and a half minutes to generate.

[image: map image]

Comment: If you have working code and you are just looking to optimize the results or see alternative approaches to the problem, your question is a better fit for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise, if there's an issue, I recommend editing your question to include code and demonstrate what's not working and what you've already tried to fix the problem.

Comment: That is a LOT of nested loops there. Aside from improving the algorithm, you may look into methods of parallelisation using Workers. While JS is single-threaded, you can have multiple Workers each dealing with a section of the grid in parallel.

Comment: Is there a way to generate only part of the map and still get similar results? I don't know of a way to do that, because it uses a scale out method so the islands can be bigger.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but the ANSI C-style of declaring all vars at the top of the scope and initializing them later seems brittle and hard to read. I'd rather scope them as tightly as possible and use `const` so there's no potential for stale values read in a different scope. With `const` and tight scoping, you know exactly what value a primitive variable has and where. There are lots of accidental globals like `for(y = 0`. That should be `for (let y = 0`.